# Successively, continuously, or sequentially, which has the meaning of "adjacent"?

Tags: adverbs

[image]

I am trying to describe the positional relationship between the boxes in the image.  I think it can be described that

> The boxes are arranged adjacent in the Z-direction.

I would like to know whether it is possible to replace " adjacent" with "successively", "continuously", or "sequentially" as follows:

> The boxes are arranged successively/continuously/sequentially in the Z-direction.

Comment: Are you writing a geometry book?

Comment: Is there a reason you want a 50-cent word? Would there be anything wrong with this? *The boxes are arranged in a row.*

Comment: I am afraid that "In a row" may be interpreted that the boxes are arrange in a line but separated from each other by a large distance.

Comment: Well, then: _The boxes are arranged in a row, close together_.

Comment: **adjacent to one another**

Comment: Since the boxes appear to be the same distance apart, you could also be specific about the distance but use simple words: _The boxes are lined up a quarter-inch apart in the Z-direction._ I'm not clear on how the directionality comes into play here, though. Can I not start looking at the boxes on either the left or the right? Without understanding the Z-direction, I'd say this is a good description: _The boxes are lined up horizontally, one-quarter-inch apart._

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, adjacent means **next to**:

**My house was adjacent to his**. But is does not necessarily imply they were touching. But it can.

Objects can be arranged in sequence or sequentially =in an ordered manner. As long as the pattern repeats. **The sequence (adverb: sequentially) is whatever order you wish impose on objects**. That said, **if all the objects are the same thing, sequence does not work so well**.

Continuous or continuous refers to time, usually, something that does not stop (continuous production). Or something that goes on unbroken for some length: There is a continuous line (as opposed to discontinuous) drawn on the map between point A and point B.

For those boxes in the picture, I would say:

**the boxes are placed (one after the other) in sequence or sequentially on a line**.

Comment: I agree with your statement that sequence doesn't work very well because all the boxes are the same. The line itself could sort of impose a sequence, I suppose, but mostly using that word would just makes me wonder how I'm supposed to determine the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. I'm not sure **adjacent** is a good choice in any case. The uncommonly used but correct adverbial form is **adjacently.**
2. You should use the word **sequentially.** **Successively** typically refers to things that come in numerical or temporal succession: **successive administrations**, **successive failed attempts**, etc. **Continuously** means without interruption, and in the OP the nuance of **continuously** would suggest that the boxes are laid against each other with no spaces in between them.

Answer (score 1):

The boxes are arranged **side-by-side**.  <sup>normal conversational</sup>

The boxes are arranged **adjacent (to one another) along the Z-axis**. <sup>more formal contexts</sup>